# iptables, differentiate ports based on hostname

Tags: iptables, dns

Is there a way, using iptables, to ACCEPT traffic from HOSTNAME1, HOSTNAME2, HOSTNAME3 to port 22 and FORWARD traffic from everyone else to a different port and make the rule persistent?

HOSTNAME1/2/3 must be used because of dynamic ip address.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - ipables doesn't understand hostnames. You can use hostnames, but they will be translated to the current IPs at the time you issue the command and will be saved as IPs. When the IP changes, you'll be forwarded incorrectly.

Comment: Adding a cron job that delete rules and re-applies it every 10 minutes is that bad?

Comment: "Bad" is a value judgement, which is an opinion - in my opinion, doing so is indeed bad for multiple reasons, but your opinion may be different. I'm not willing to say you absolutely should not ever do this, but I know I wouldn't do it.